Variable defined; unexpectedly becomes undefined
This script is intended to create a customize PDF file based on the Google Form responses. This worked a few days back and suddenly it stopped executing.
The variable/property in question ("info") seems to be present but it is still returning an error of being undefined
For reference, this is the script:
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  
  const info = e.namedValues;  
  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PDFs").getRange(entryRow,19).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl()); 

  sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email Address'][0],pdfFile);
  
}

function sendEmail(email,pdfFile) {  
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Here's your Material Requisition Form", "Hello,\n\nThank you for submitting a material requisition. \n\nAs this is a self declaration form there is no further approval required. \n\nPlease print and attach this form to all requested materials. \n\nMany thanks for your cooperation. \n\nKind regards,\nLogistics Team", {
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'Logistics Team'    
  });
  GmailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "Material Requisition Form for SAP Transaction", "Hello,\n\nKindly transact the following material requisiton form in SAP. \n\nMany thanks for your cooperation. \n\nKind regards,\nLogistics Team", {
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'Logistics Team'    
  });
}

This is the variable/property is based from the Google Form responses (Google Sheets)

This is the error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Date of Request')
createPDF @ Code.gs:35

"info" object was checked to have "Date of Request" (as shown in the heading of the form responses in Google Sheet)

Editor's note:
Below there is the createPDF function taken from the revision 1 of this question
function createPDF(info) {
        
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1GiY42M3rTq36M9pnUq7Y6RE1qQ8TFN8X");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1bkzpVTURICEvcJWemFGaOYTZSdeF_XNj");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1UfFzcIdG1DCAYpk-NWSiA7bEoz1ZSJXeuV_9-Okw_vg");

  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body  = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Date of Request}",info['Date of Request'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Requestor}",info['Requestor'][0]);
  body.replaceTest("{Line}",info['Line'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Cost Centre}", info['Cost Centre (if known)'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Project Name}", info['Project Name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Project Code}", info['Project Code'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{PN}", info['Part Number or Serial Number'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Reason for Requirement}", info['Reason for Requirement'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Quantity}", info['Quantity'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Description}", info['Description'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Have}", info['Have these products been deemed scrap by the Linelead/Area owner?'][0]);
  openDoc.saveAndClose();


  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Requestor'][0] + " " + info['Date of Request'][0]);
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);  
  return pdfFile;
}


Please add a [mcve]

Among others, please specify what your info object is.

I presume that your info object is the namedValues object.  Are you possibly not using the correct onFormSubmit trigger.  There are two.  One is for the form and one is for the spreadsheet. The event objects are totally different.

The question doesn't include the function mentioned in the error message. Also it needs more focus (only one question per post)

I believe your Additional Query is not anymore related to your original post and is already another issue. Please focus on your original issue to avoid any further confusion. You may post another question for your additional issue.

I noticed that an answer has been posted and you have already thanked the user who posted it. Please take note that you may upvote/accept the answer if it solved your issue.

@PatrickdC The OP doesn't yet have enough reputation points to upvote. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

@Wicket my bad, i just noticed the OP's rep. I thought it was higher due to the activity in this post. Anyway, the OP should accept the answer IF it solves the issue.

Directly creating the info object

Revised answer based on the updated code provided.

A possible reason why your code doesn’t work is that using e.namedValues can cause issues if there are mismatched field names or missing values, which might lead to undefined errors when you try to access them. I would recommend creating the info object directly from the spreadsheet data instead. This way, you ensure that each value is correctly wrapped in an array and matches what you expect. Not only does this help prevent errors, but it also makes your code more efficient and easier to read.
NOTE: the removeFile() has already been deprecated, I removed it from your code by rendering it as a comment.
UPDATED CODE:
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PDFs");
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  const rowData = sheet.getRange(entryRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  const info = {
    'Email Address': [rowData[1]],
    'Date of Request': [rowData[2]],
    'Requestor': [rowData[3]],
    'Line': [rowData[4]],
    'Cost Centre (if known)': [rowData[5]],
    'Project Name': [rowData[6]],
    'Project Code': [rowData[7]],
    'Part Number or Serial Number': [rowData[8]],
    'Reason for Requirement': [rowData[9]],
    'Quantity': [rowData[10]]
  };

  const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 19).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
  sendEmail(info['Email Address'][0], pdfFile);
}

function createPDF(info) {
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1GiY42M3rTq36M9pnUq7Y6RE1qQ8TFN8X");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1bkzpVTURICEvcJWemFGaOYTZSdeF_XNj");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1UfFzcIdG1DCAYpk-NWSiA7bEoz1ZSJXeuV_9-Okw_vg");

  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body  = openDoc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{Date of Request}", info['Date of Request'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Requestor}", info['Requestor'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Line}", info['Line'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Cost Centre}", info['Cost Centre (if known)'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Project Name}", info['Project Name'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Project Code}", info['Project Code'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{PN}", info['Part Number or Serial Number'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Reason for Requirement}", info['Reason for Requirement'][0] || "");
  body.replaceText("{Quantity}", info['Quantity'][0] || "");

  openDoc.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Requestor'][0] + " " + info['Date of Request'][0]);
  //tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);  
  return pdfFile;
}

function sendEmail(email, pdfFile) {
  const subjectUser = "Here's your Material Requisition Form";
  const bodyUser = "Hello,\n\nThank you for submitting a material requisition. \n\nAs this is a self-declaration form, there is no further approval required. \n\nPlease print and attach this form to all requested materials. \n\nMany thanks for your cooperation. \n\nKind regards,\nLogistics Team";

  const subjectAdmin = "Material Requisition Form for SAP Transaction";
  const bodyAdmin = "Hello,\n\nKindly transact the following material requisition form in SAP. \n\nMany thanks for your cooperation. \n\nKind regards,\nLogistics Team";

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subjectUser, bodyUser, {
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'Logistics Team'
  });

  GmailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", subjectAdmin, bodyAdmin, {
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'Logistics Team'
  });
}

Please be aware that you need to install a trigger in order to make your code work whenever a user submits the form, you can do it by making an installable trigger, or run the code below. Additionally, be careful with running the code multiple times as it can send the email repeatedly depending on the trigger you have created/run.
function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('afterFormSubmit')
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}

OUTPUT:

Please revise the code above based on your project needs, especially that I did not include the last 2 questions of the form.
REFERENCES:

Manage triggers manually
Event Objects
Remove File


removeFile is deprecated and it seems to me that the op wants to create a custom pdf file for each submission and not necessarily for all of them at one time and the event object for a form submission has a namedValues object and each value is infact an array.

@Cooper I do understand your perspective regarding my answer and Yes, the removeFile is deprecated. References used in the post were meant to back fact based answers on my post. Also another thing the second point you are referring about this is presuming that OP is using the onSubmit for and passing responses. The answer provided on my post were meant to provide alternative perspective on how to get the code working again without any presumption on the limitation the OP is having due to lack of information on the OP's post.

I do apologize for the confusion about my answer I am editing it to provide clearer information in accordance to the thoughts that I was hoping to share.

The question doesn't include anything suggesting that the function parameter data comes from Google Sheets. Please explain why you are proposing a function that uses SpredsheetApp.

@ELSRY Thanks for your helpful response . I just wanted to provide some additional context. The script you reviewed is actually just a part of a larger script that automates the entire process of generating PDFs from form responses and emailing them back to the respondents. To give you a better understanding of the full context, I've updated the complete script in the post. I hope this will be helpful in further analyzing the issue and providing any additional recommendations

@Wicket I think that the recent comment of the OP clarifies a little bit about your current comment. As this is a part of a bigger script, and the current post doesn't provide that information yet. the basis of my answer is from the image that came from the OP's post wherein it references a spreadsheet.

@ELSRY how do I replace the "info" in the afterFormSubmit if I will use the updated code? Please see code below: function afterFormSubmit(e) {
const info = e.namedValues;
const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email Address'][0],pdfFile);
}

Please see the revised code above. And since you have provided the necessary code, I would recommend that you remain with your code structure as the OnformSubmit is needed based on your requirements. I made some changes to the afterFormSubmit(e), and improvement on the rest.

If you have any questions or concerns with regards to the answer I have provided, please do let me know.

@ELSRY the code works! and I've successfully received the emails with the PDF attached. However, I've noticed that the PDF file being generated based on the row above the last submitted line in the form response (ie, The latest form submitted was from Tester 06, but the PDF file that was generated and emailed was for Tester 05. There seems to be a mismatch between the submitted form data and the PDF content.). As you can see in the image link, the PDF content doesn't match the latest entry.
link

I understand that my code is not working properly on your end as intended. I have updated the code and added the line const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();, and revised the line sheet.getRange(lastRow, 19).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl()); in the afterFormSubmit(e) function. Kindly note that there is a limitation for this code as it will always paste the link in the lastRow of the data that you are trying to create/send.

Click the "edited ... mins ago" beside the Flag button of my answer for easier identification of the revised code. Please feel free to give it a try and let me know how it turns out.

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
